# prove function $u(x)=x*{w(x)}$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

**giving a function $u(x)=x*w(x)$ and giving that  $w(x)$ is defined for all $x$ 

prove that if $w(x)$ is differentiable at x=0 then $u(x)=x*w(x)$ is differentiable at x=0

how do I prove $w(x)$ is differentiable** 


my attempt:
I tried to extract the function $w(x)$ from the function $u(x)$ the result is $w(x)=\frac{u(x)}{x}$ 
but that make the function not defined at x=0 and that breaks the equation
I tried finding $w'(x)$ using the $lim[\frac{w(x+h)-w(x)}{h}$]
I get $lim_{x\to0^+}=\infty$ and $lim_{x\to0^-}=-\infty$ and that's the opposite  of what I need
do

how do I prove $w(x)$ is differentiable or how do I find $w(x)$

Comment: You are asked to prove that $u$ is differentiable, right? Why do you seem to attempt proving $w$ is differentiable?

Comment: I need to prove that if $w(x)$ at x=0 is differentiable then $u(x)$ is differentiable at x=0

Comment: Yes, but your last sentence asks how to prove $w$ is differentiable. The question already tells you that $w$ is differentiable.